# Did "ancient people who spoke languages that didn't have words for numbers greater than three" keep track of sheep using stones?

Tags: history

In the TED-Ed [video](https://ed.ted.com/lessons/how-big-is-infinity) "[How big is infinity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPA3bwVVzGI)" [Dennis Wildfogel](https://denniswildfogel.wordpress.com/about/) says (at the 50 second mark) this about "matching being more fundamental than counting":

> In fact, we think that some ancient people who spoke languages that didn't have words for numbers greater than three used this sort of magic. For instance, if you let your sheep out of a pen to graze, you cna keep track of how many went out by setting aside a stone for each one, and putting those stones back one by one when the sheep return, so you know if any are missing without really counting.

Is there any evidence that "ancient people who spoke languages that didn't have words for numbers greater than three" used this method to keep track of sheep?

Comment: Please re-tag and suggest improvements as you see fit. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you keep asking plain history questions here. Why do you think this is such a strange claim? What makes you doubt that this happened?

Comment: @pipe I guess I may tend to be more interested in history. This is reflected in my questions. However, I don't think this is a "plain history question." Why do you think so? As for your questions: What makes you doubt that this happened? I think: Why do you think this happened? Well, I am learning something ancient people did with sheep in a math video?

Comment: I am looking at my questions, and I think <50% relate to history. I would say ~15% are definitely historical in focus.

Comment: @BarryHarrison That topic is better discussed in chat. I've left you [a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49999954#49999954) there.

Comment: Click join this room at the bottom.